# How to autocomplete list of all arguments to function in PyCharm?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

How to autocomplete list of all arguments to function in PyCharm?

I want to autocomplete arguments for function like in PyDev.

```
def do(a, b, c):
   pass
```

After typing `do(<cursor here>)` I want to autocomplete `to do(a, b, c)` - is it possible in PyCharm or hidden too much. It is very useful in large programs.

Now I can autocomplete single argument but it is not enough.

Comment: do(<cursor>) then alt+space (maybe something other I type a lot of code so probably all combos know in any other editor) not works - not found help for it after confusion.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to auto complete multiple arguments like this, not without the help of some sort of AI auto complete plugin.

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/auto-completing-code.html)

you can do these things in PyCharm to help with autocompletion of code -- which is what i'm understanding you to need help with:

- Basic code completion on ⌃Space.
- Type completion on ⌃⇧Space.
- Completing punctuation on ⏎.
- Completing statements with smart ⏎.
- Completing paths in the Select Path dialog.
- Expanding words with ⌥/.

see documentation link above for more detailed info on each. lots of pictures and help for each of the above. hope this helps.

Comment: But which of these is the correct one for the OP? I tried all and couldn't get any of them to autocomplete function parameters like this

Comment: `ctrl + space` will list one named argument at a time (e.g. `arg_1=`), so not quite what the OP wanted, little help but more than nothing. 

BTW +1 for the OP's request - in case the Jetbrains dudes ever read this.